# How to change woocommerce description tag name

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Is it possible to change the main description tag name of woocommerce, wich is displayed on single product pages? I tried to change it via the language file and inside the tab.php file, but it's still using the value **description**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if there is a tab.php file. Never heard of that, but add this snippet to the functions.php file and it will work.

```
    //Rename Description
    add_filter('woocommerce_product_description_heading', '__return_false');   
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'woo_rename_tabs', 98 );

    function woo_rename_tabs( $tabs ) {

    $tabs['description']['title'] = __( 'Designmerkmale' );     

    return $tabs;
}
```